# "Article I" is getting added to Heading 1 Style in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to copy Styles from a Word template to another Word file. The code I am using is as follow:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim stl As Style
'On Error GoTo theCopy
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ActiveDocument.CopyStylesFromTemplate("C:\Users\rajtilak\Desktop\Report.dotx")

p = ActiveDocument.Sections.Count

For j = 1 To p
    'Header
    If ActiveDocument.Sections(j).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = True Then
    ActiveDocument.Sections(j).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = False
    End If
        If ActiveDocument.Sections(j).Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).LinkToPrevious = True Then
        ActiveDocument.Sections(j).Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).LinkToPrevious = False
    End If

    'Footer
    If ActiveDocument.Sections(j).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = True Then
    ActiveDocument.Sections(j).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = False
    End If
        If ActiveDocument.Sections(j).Footers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).LinkToPrevious = True Then
        ActiveDocument.Sections(j).Footers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).LinkToPrevious = False
    End If
Next j

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Styles Successfully Copied"

End Sub
```

This is working fine. However, after copying the Styles, when I am trying to change the default Font for all styles by using the following code, the phrase "Article I" is getting appended to the Style:

```
For Each stl In ActiveDocument.Styles
    stl.Font.Name = "Georgia"
Next
```

Can anybody please help me understand why this is happening? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your`CommandButton1_Click` procedure doesn't copy any styles. It just de-links headers and footers from each other (or attempts to do so - I somehow doubt that it would work).

Your second code snippet tries to change the font name for all styles in the ActiveDocument. That is a very tall order because there are used styles and unused styles, default styles and user-defined styles, dozens of them. There are paragraph styles and character styles, as well as those which can be both.

Each style has its own `Font` object. Each Font object has a `Name` property but some of the styles are formatted to inherit their `Font` from other styles. A blanket order like you attempt must create confusion, for example, when your code tries to change the name of a font which is inherited from another font whose name will be changed only later in the loop. Honestly, there is no telling what destruction that code will cause or what the result will be.

When you attempt to change styles it is best to submit them to your surgery one at a time. However, it's quite possible that the following line of code will do much of what you want.

```
ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal).Font.Name = "Georgia"
```

This will change the `Normal` style font, and since most of what you mostly do uses the `Normal` font the change will be quite far-reaching.

As for copying styles between documents, I suggest that you google for "Copy styles from another document". This can be done with a few clicks much more efficiently than any VBA code you might write.

Comment: Does the following piece of code not imports the styles?

  
  ActiveDocument.CopyStylesFromTemplate("C:\Users\rajtilak\Desktop\Report.dotx")

Comment: Wait, it worked! The phrase is not getting appended by changing the Normal style instead of all styles like I was doing. Thank you so much!